# How do I set stylelint to fix errors automatically?

Tags: stylelint

`stylelint *.css --fix` not working as expect. Error reporting works well but a file is not fixed.

package.json

```
{
  "devDependencies": {
    "stylelint": "^11.1.1",
    "stylelint-config-recess-order": "^2.0.3"
  }
}
```

.stylelintrc.json

```
{
  "extends": "stylelint-config-recess-order"
}
```

style.css (ugly-order properties)

```css
.test {
  height: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  width: 100%;
}
```

command

```sh
$ npx stylelint style.css --fix
```

output

```sh
style.css
 4:3  ✖  Expected "width" to come before "margin"   order/properties-order
```

Error reporting is fine.
I expect auto-fixing works for a file.

Comment: The same setting and config works fine on my computer(macOS), no report but the ugly-order properties had been fixed after running it.

Comment: Thanks, @ahgood. It was resolved as I posted below.

Comment: I have the same problem! Applied your answer but none effective! I'm using Webstorm!

Answer (score 10):

### auto-correct options for Stylelint. It fixes all issues for me.

`To check the errors first:`

```
npx stylelint "**/*.{css,scss}"
```

`To fix the issues for all files (auto-correct options)`

```
npx stylelint "**/*.{css,scss}" --fix
```

`If you want to change it for a specific file.`

```
/npx stylelint src/index.css --fix 

[your file name and path may need to be modified according to your one]
```

Answer (score 4):

Resolved. I removed `node_modules` and `package-lock.json`. After that I ran `npm i`. I'm not sure about the cause but works well now.

Answer (score 3):

Try `npx stylelint --fix style.css` (note the `--fix` is before the CSS files path).

Comment: Yeah the accepted answer did't work. Using --fix after `npx stylelint` will fix the problem.

Comment: Neither answer works.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that this was happening for untracked files. In my case they were `.scss` files. What I did was,

1. Added an exception of the file to `.stylelintignore`
2. Commited the file to the repo
3. Removed the exception of the file from `.stylelintignore`
4. Had the errors reported to my terminal and run `npx stylelint src/scss/_file.scss --fix`
5. All the fixable errors were fixed

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I used old version of prettier. Upgrading it to latest fixed my problem

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).